# Does +Spell Damage affect traps?

Tags: hearthstone

The hunter has 2 traps that deal damage (Snipe & Explosive Trap).  I was wondering if those are affected by +Spell Damage like other spells.

And if they are affected, when does that happen?  Does the spell damage of when you cast the secret lock into the card, or is it calculated based on the spell damage you have when the secret is revealed.

Comment: If anyone has run into this and knows the answer, or has the ability to test that would be awesome, otherwise I will test it this weekend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spell Damage affects only cards that are of type *Spell* - they have a "Spell" label sticked to the bottom of the card, when you hover your mouse over it.

There are three types of cards in Hearthstone:

- Minion
- Weapon
- Spell

Traps, or more precisely Secrets, *are* Spells and are affected by Spell Damage, but in a slightly different way than usual. The bonus to damage dealt by Secrets is applied when it triggers, and not when it is being cast.

There are a couple visual cues in game that let you see which cards get affected by Spell Damage:

1. When you have a minion with +Spell Damage on the table, all the spells in your hand that deal some damage display the number of damage already increased by all the +Spell Damage effects currently active. Additionally the number is surrounded by asterisk (*).
2. When you hover your mouse over your minion with +Spell Damage on your battlefield, all the cards in your hand, that are affected by the effect, get highlighted with a purplish glitter for a few seconds.

Comment: But traps technically count as a "Spell" when they are cast, for purposes of abilities that trigger on spell cast, such as Gadgetzan Auctioneer.  Thus I was unsure about their interaction with Spell Damage.

Comment: @DiabloMonkey That's a valid point I guess. It seems there's little discrepancy to how the term 'spell' is being used. When it comes to auctioneer it looks like it just means 'non-creature' cards. But I'm almost sure the 'spell' label I mentioned in my answer isn't present on every non-creature card - I'll have to check it, I guess. Were it true, that all the non-creature cards have the label, then the Spell Power should be read as - your spells deal additional damage when being cast, as opposed to, e.g. a secret triggering.

Comment: I think maybe it is a spell when you cast it, and that spell creates a (secret) trap. There would have to be a separate card that would say "+1 Secret Damage" I guess. But not all non-creatures are spells (weapons do not give you card draw with the Auctioneer).

Comment: This answer is incorrect. +Spell Damage _does_ affect traps that do damage.

Comment: This has apparently changed since the time this answer was posted. As of now, @ken.ganong is right and the above answer is no longer correct.

Comment: @scenia I had no idea such change was made. Anyone with some info on how the +spell damage works with traps now, please feel free to edit my answer, or post a new one.

Comment: I haven't had the chance to try this a lot, so I can only tell you it does indeed increase the damage now. I don't know if it sets the amount when you play the secret of if the amount of +Spell Damage when the Secret triggers counts.

Comment: @DiabloMonkey I would recommend updating which answer is correct, since this one is at least incorrect now. That or ykb should update his answer.

Comment: Mage counter spell counters a trap right?

Comment: @AtlasEU Counterspell's text says: "When your opponent *casts* a spell, Counter it.", so if it were already on the table, when a hunter tries to cast a trap it would counter it. But if the trap, or any other Secret, was cast before, Counterspell **wouldn't** prevent the effect of this Secret being triggered.

Answer (score 16):

**Yes.**

The bonus is calculated when traps are *triggered*. According to forum comments it worked like this at least as far back as October 2013. (unable to find any other comments or patch notes about a change)

[image]

[image]

[image]

*Thanks to DakaPaka for help testing, albeit unknowingly.*